# Assign a Row of a named area to a ranged variable

Tags: excel, vba, row, variable-assignment, named-ranges

I want to assign a area of a worksheet to a name and then assign each row of that named area to a ranged variable in VBA.

I am able to assign the named area to a ranged variable but only if I pass the whole area. If I try using .Rows() to save only a specific Row to a ranged variable, Im unable to access any values that should be in the named variable.

Example:

```
Dim FirstRow as range: set FirstRow = Worksheets("worksheetname").Range("NamedArea").Rows(1)

'Trying to get out any value:
Debug.Print FirstRow 'Runtime Error 13: types incompatible
Debug.Print FirstRow(1) 'Runtime Error 13: types incompatible
Debug.Print FirstRow(1,1) 'Runtime Error 13: types incompatible

'Trying to iterate through values:
For each i in FirstRow
   Debug.Print "hello" ' Output: "hello" 'only once
   Debug.Print "i" 'Runtime Error
next i
```

Comment: @CDP1802 Why don't you undelete your post?

Comment: @vbasic2008 I thought your comment would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: a simple example with named range]

```
'the code must be in the sheets module

Private Sub example()
   Dim i As Range, FirstRow As Range, cc As Long
   
   Set FirstRow = Me.Range("NamedArea").Rows(1)
   
   Debug.Print FirstRow.Address
   Debug.Print FirstRow.Cells(1, 1)

   For Each i In FirstRow.Cells
      cc = cc + 1
      Debug.Print cc & ". " & i.Address & " = " & i.Value
   Next i
   
End Sub


'if you want to set this sub in a module out of any sheet's module, 'the better is to call it with two parameters:

Public Sub example(ws As Worksheet, rngName As String)
   Dim i As Range, FirstRow As Range, cc As Long
   
   Set FirstRow = ws.Range(rngName).Rows(1)
   
   Debug.Print FirstRow.Address
   Debug.Print FirstRow.Cells(1, 1)

   For Each i In FirstRow.Cells
      cc = cc + 1
      Debug.Print cc & ". " & i.Address & " = " & i.Value
   Next i
   
End Sub


'and from a sheet's module call it like this:

Private Sub callExample()
   Call example(Me, "NameOfAnyNamedRange")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to use this outside of the respective sheet module?

Comment: nvm I can just do it with the worksheets("sheetname"). Thanks a lot